# PHP hangs but continues when ctl -c

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a php script that runs a stored procedure in SQL. The stored procedure will run around 25 minutes when executed on sqlquery. But when run on php it will hang until I exit the program (ctr-c)

How to handle this situation?

Here is a sample code

```
<?php

ini_set("max_excution_time", 1800);
ini_set("max_input_time", 1800);
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 1800);
ini_set("mssql.connect_timeout", 1800);
ini_set("mssql.timeout", 1800);
ini_set("mysql.connect_timeout", 1800);

$dsn = "sqlsrv:server=myDatase123\analysis;Database=Customers";

$storedProcedures = array( 
    '[storedProcedure1]', 
    '[storedProcedure2]' 
    );

try{
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, NULL, NULL);
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    if($conn){
        foreach ($storedProcedures as $procedure) {
            $sth = $conn->query($procedure);
            if ($sth) {
                print "success -".$procedure.PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                print "error on ".$procedure.PHP_EOL;
            }
        }

    } else {
            print "error connecting".$procedure.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $conn = null;
}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: What does `when executed on sqlquery` mean?  What does `[storedProcedure1]` look like exactly?

Comment: hi dont panic, when executed on sqlquery means - if i run the script on toad for sql or sql server management studuio. the content of storedProcudure1 is a number of joins and queries.

Comment: No, I mean really what does it look like?  `CALL some_procedure`?

Comment: yes Don't Panic

Comment: Do your procedures have any input parameters?

Comment: the parameters is inside the procedures.

Comment: Have you tried `prepare` and `execute`, as [described in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)?

Comment: yes i have done that.